# full table scan for an OR in a WHERE statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database, explain

So I have this query

```
EXPLAIN SELECT r.* FROM r_table r
        LEFT JOIN f_table f ON f.id = r.fid
        LEFT JOIN f_table ff ON r.fid = 0 AND r.type = 'f' AND r.id = ff.id
      WHERE (r.fid = 0 AND ff.cid = 421563) OR (r.fid <> 0 AND f.cid = 421563);
```

And it's performing a full table scan on table r

Explain output:

```
1   SIMPLE      r   ALL Index1              2314    Using where
1   SIMPLE      f   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   r.fid   1   Using where
1   SIMPLE      ff  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   r.id    1   Using where
```

How can I modify this query to make it not perform a full table scan?
I know that I can probably use UNION nonetheless I'd rather not do UNION unless necessary.

### EDIT

Rewriting the query into a UNION indeed worked...here's the UNION query

```
EXPLAIN SELECT r.* FROM r_table r
        LEFT JOIN f_table f ON r.fid <> 0 AND f.id = r.fid
      WHERE f.cid = 421563
UNION SELECT r.* FROM r_table r
        LEFT JOIN f_table ff ON r.fid = 0 AND r.obj_type = 'f' AND r.obj_id = ff.id
      WHERE ff.cid = 421563;
```

And explain output

```
'2', 'UNION', 'ff', 'ref', 'PRIMARY,cid', 'cid', '4', 'const', '2', 'Using where; Using index'
'2', 'UNION', 'r', 'ref', 'Index1,obj_id_type', 'Index1', '13', 'const,const,ff.id', '1', 'Using where'
'1', 'PRIMARY', 'f', 'ref', 'PRIMARY,cid', 'cid', '4', 'const', '2', 'Using where; Using index'
'1', 'PRIMARY', 'r', 'ref', 'Index1', 'Index1', '4', 'f.id', '1', ''
NULL, 'UNION RESULT', '<union1,2>', 'ALL', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, ''
```

But once again, I would rather not do a UNION for this

Comment: I suspect that r.fid = 0 and r.type = 'f' should not be part of the join to the ff_table.  those should be part of the where clause.

Comment: With the r.fid columns being used in both conditions and with no `LIMIT` in the query, my understanding is that it has to scan full table to fetch all the matching records.

Comment: So, you only want to join `ff_table` when `r.fid` is `0`?

Comment: Suspect even a UNION won't help as you are getting every row from r_table

Comment: Sounds like you need an index on `r.fid` (and possibly `ff.cid` and `f.cid`).

Comment: there are already indices on those...Also I made a mistake on the query...ff_table is actually f_table (they're the same table with the table with alias f)

Comment: It's foobar tables and foobar queries, so I can't say what is correct. But why do you want to avoid union? There are different ways to combine sets. You must choose the proper way and that may be a union.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move the filters on ff.cid and f.cid from the where clause to the join.  In fact, since you are doing a left join, you have to do this anyway.

Comment: did that still doing full table scan